# Update multiple column value from one column of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

In My table there have two columns.
Table structure is:

Combined's data type is `varchar(50)` and First's data type is `int`.

```
ID--Combined -----------First 

1---1.2.3.4-------------- null

2---3.8.6.9-------------- null
```

I want to convert it to

```
ID---Combined -----------First 

1---1.2.3.4-------------- 1

2---3.8.6.9-------------- 3
```

I wrote this lines of code

```
UPDATE dbo.Test 
SET dbo.Test.First = CAST(SUBSTRING(T.Combined,1,1) AS INT)  
FROM dbo.Test as T 
WHERE T.ID = dbo.Test.ID;
```

But my code gives that error '`The multi-part identifier "dbo.Test.ID" could not be bound.`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the update-from syntax here. Since you want your `First` column to relate to the `Combined` column **of the same row**, a simple update statement will do:

```
UPDATE dbo.Test
SET    dbo.Test.First = CAST(SUBSTRING(dbo.Test.Combined, 1, 1) AS INT)
```